# desperately need help: Ajax.beginform calling twice, the second one with previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

so guys after lot of debugging i came to know that with in my application containing a partial view with few check boxes and a submit button, the controller/JS is called twice.
here's the twist:

1. when ever the JS is called twice. in First request, it saves the correct values of check boxes then in next request it saves the previous values that were available.
2. This calling doesnt happen  consistently it happen randomly.Also checked for any issues with data or code but there is no problem.So problem is generated at AJAX call itself but i am unable to find the cause.

Can someone help me in figuring this out.i am really desperate.
my code as follows:

My Partial View:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "TimeLineObject.OnAjaxComplete", OnSuccess = "", OnBegin = "TimeLineObject.OnAjaxBegin", UpdateTargetId = "divEditorContent", OnFailure = "insertfailure" }, new { @class = "form-inline", id = "searchForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m =>m.IsSave)
    <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Document </th>
        <th>Input Type</th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.model[i].Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.model[i].Id)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.model[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "form-control" })

            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.model[i].DocumentName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.model[i].InputType
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
 </table>
}
```

My controller:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    [ValidateInput(true), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult action(object documents)
    {
        using (CaseConfigManager manager = new CaseConfigManager())
        {
            var response = manager.layer2(documents.data,  SessionId);

            if (response.Status)
            {
                return this.PartialView("_Message", new MessageModel() { Type = MessageType.Success, Message = response.Message, Code = ClientStatussCode.TimeLine });
            }
            else
            {
                return this.PartialView("_Message", new MessageModel() { Type = MessageType.Warning, Message = response.Message, Code = ClientStatussCode.TimeLine });
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the save button is in Timeline page from where partial views are generated.

TimeLine JS:

```
OnAjaxBegin: function () {
    debugger;
    $('#formsave').attr('disabled', true);
},
OnAjaxComplete: function () {
    debugger;
    $('#formsave').attr('disabled', false);
    RegisterAutoCompute();
    RegisterValidation();
    TimeLineObject.RegisterDatePicker();
},
OnAjaxSuccess: function (HTML, Message) {
    TimeLineObject.FillHtmlContent(HTML);
    TimeLineObject.OnCloseClick();
    TimeLineObject.Message(Message);
},
OnAjaxFailure: function (error) {
    TimeLineObject.Message(TimeLineObject.Alerts.AjaxFail);
},
```

This above OnAjaxBegin is getting called twice.

Answer (score 0):

The begin here, gets called once

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    [ValidateInput(true), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public PartialViewResult IndexValid100(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return PartialView("_APartialViewWithJS");
    }

    public ActionResult IndexValid100()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());

    }
```

_APartialViewWithJS.cshtml

```
A Partial View
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    @*!!!!You need the unotrusive-ajax.min.js*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive@3.2.4/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function onAjaxBegin() {
                alert("ap");
            }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
    {
             UpdateTargetId = "divEditorContent",
             OnBegin = "onAjaxBegin"
    }
    ))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Document </th>
                <th>Input Type</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
    <div id="divEditorContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @kblau as suggested i have added the **httppost attribute** and i have that **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** in layout page.

Comment: hi @kblau its still not working. onething i observe is that the AJAX is getting called twice.

Comment: @TejaswiPandava what else are you doing different than me, which would cause the onajaxbegin to be called twice?

Comment: so in my setup the following things are different:
1. The **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** file is in layout page.
2. The button "<button type="button" class="b" id="formpartialsave" onclick="TimeLineObject.function()">Save</button>" is in timeline view
apart from these there is no other difference.

Comment: @Tejaswi Pandava Are you suppose to have an onlick event on the button?  Are you suppose to just use the OnBegin withing the AjaxOptions?